# How to get MySQL resource usage per user

Tags: linux, mysql, cpu-usage, memory-usage

I want to know is there anyway to get CPU usage per user in MySQL? for example I have 3 different users 'user1', 'user2'  and 'user3'. I want to get the average/real time memory usage and CPU usage of these users.I googled a lot but I did not find any suitable tool. Maybe I can get these data from MySQL queries, but I don't know where are they stored.

Comment: I am not sure if we can do that, since mysql is parent process and mysql user comes underneath, Alternative is restrict(pin it) mysql process to particular CPU, by that way no other process can use that core and you can calculate the process cpu usage(not user), To restrict the number of users you can write the triggers which can prevent user addition after particular number of user exceed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want it?  If it is to see who is using the CPU more, then use the slowlog and some digest such as pt-query-digest.

In a well-tuned production system the CPU is *not* heavily used.  So it should not matter who is using the CPU.

See also:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237969/how-to-get-cpu-usage-in-mysql-per-user

Comment: No I don't want to find the user who uses more CPU. It can easily be find out from mysql process list and slow queries. I want to calculate and display the overall CPU usage of a user to tell him/her to pay for the resources. I want to create a `pay as you go` service. So I need to know the CPU usage of MySQL too.

Comment: @Sinai - OK.  I don't think such exists.  Charging for disk space is probably easy.

Comment: What about audit? Is there any audit rule to do such thing for me? Calculating Disk space is easy but not enough :D